# how to post json data with header i am using this code but its not working

Tags: c#, asp.net, json

var settings = {
      "async": true,
      "crossDomain": true,
      "url": "http://api.XXXXX.com/SharedServices/SharedData.svc/rest/Authenticate",
      "method": "POST",
     "headers": {
        "content-type": "application/json",
  },
      "processData": false,
      "data": "{\r\n                \"ClientId\": \"ApiIntegration\",\r\n                \"UserName\": \"XXXXX\",\r\n                \"Password\": \"XXXXXX@12\",\r\n                \"EndUserIp\": \"192.168.1.9\"\r\n}"
};

$.ajax(settings).done(function (response) {
  console.log(response);
});

Comment: And your actual question is...?

Comment: This doesn't make anything clearer. What have you tried so far? Do you get any exceptions? ....

Comment: Webforms and MVC are not the same thing.  Are you asking how to use WebAPI in Webforms?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there is some mistaken i did in another code this is correct.

```
enter var settings = {
"async": true,
"crossDomain": true,
"url": "http://api.XXXXX.com/SharedServices/SharedData.svc/rest/Authenticate",
"method": "POST",
"headers": {"content-type": "application/json", },
"processData": false,
"data": "{\r\n \"ClientId\": \"ApiIntegration\",\r\n \"UserName\": \"XXXXX\",\r\n \"Password\": \"XXXXXX@12\",\r\n \"EndUserIp\": \"192.168.1.9\"\r\n}"};
$.ajax(settings).done(function (response) {
console.log(response); });
```